# YQL Scraping: Follow Links One Level Down?

Tags: web-scraping, yql

Does YQl have a good method of scraping a web page but also following the links of that web page to get further details?

An example would be something like a blog where the index page displays the title of each news entry but you need to click on that title link to get the news story and associated pictures etc. I need to grab the data from each news entry page and deal with paginated results on the index page too.

If YQL is capable of this can anyone provide any examples? If it isn't can anyone suggest a good alternative?

Answer (score 0):

We solved similar problem by hosting a service in AppEngine which would invoke YQL first to get the links. Then iterate the links to fetch the content of the URL.